# PHP MySql Fetch produces "false" instead of a dataset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to create an aggregated data set for graphing (min and max values of every X rows) and I'm not getting the results I expect.  I can run the query from PHPMyAdmin and it works perfectly, I get a single row with two columns.  However, when I use PDO it simply produces `false` instead of an array as I expect.

```
// Get an min/max aggregated dataset
$aggregatedData = [];
echo (string)$count . "<br>"; // DEBUG

$query = "SELECT MIN(channel1) AS MinVal, MAX(channel1) AS MaxVal FROM "
        . "(SELECT channel1 FROM datacache WHERE fileId = ? ORDER BY time LIMIT ?,?) subset"; 

$sql = $conn->prepare($query);

while ($offset < $count)
{
    $sql->execute([$chart, $offset, $aggregate]);
    echo $chart . ", " . $offset . ", " . $aggregate . "<br>"; // DEBUG

    $data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data)."<br>"; // DEBUG

    array_push($aggregatedData, $data["MinVal"], $data["MaxVal"]);
    $offset += $aggregate;
}

echo json_encode($aggregatedData); //AJAX Export
```

My debug output is as follows (excerpt for brevity)

```
1000004
37, 0, 50
false
37, 50, 50
false
37, 100, 50
false
37, 150, 50
false
37, 200, 50
false
```

Note: this was not a duplicate as suggested.

Comment: $count is another SQL query a bit earlier in the script that simply pulls the total rows for the fileId.  The debug shows that is working correctly.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: `echo $sql->errorInfo();`

Comment: @PatrickQ It produces bool(false)

Comment: @AbraCadaver var_dump($sql->errorInfo()); produces the following.  However I can execute this query manually (with appropriate values) and it works, so I am confused by that.

 

array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(164) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','50') subset' at line 1" }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDOStatement::execute()` treats all array values passed as strings `PDO::PARAM_STR`, which is not the case for your `LIMIT ?,?` values which need to be integers `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

You probably need use `PDOStatement::bindParam()` with `PDO::PARAM_INT` instead. 
 Also, you can do this outside of the loop once since the variables are bound by reference:

```
$sql->bindParam(1, $chart, PDO::PARAM_INT);  // or whatever it is
$sql->bindParam(2, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(3, $aggregate, PDO::PARAM_INT);

while ($offset < $count)
{
    $sql->execute();
    $data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    array_push($aggregatedData, $data["MinVal"], $data["MaxVal"]);
    $offset += $aggregate;
}
```

Comment: This was correct, thank you.  I edited to add parameter indexes to the bindParam.

Comment: Thanks, forgot that. Also, a note about not needing it in the loop.